# Need to create a for each loop with changing variable in t-sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have three integers 7, 3, and 2.

I want to write a script that loops changing my variable each time then executing a SQL request using that changed variable for each changes variable.  I am not sure how to do this.

I know how to declare a variable

```
declare @myvariable int;
set @myvariable = 7

select * 
from mytable 
where field1 = @myvariable
```

Please help

Comment: What is the upper and lower limit of loop

Answer (score 1):

You can use tablevariable for this.

Method-1 using While loop

```
DECLARE @TableVariable TABLE (
    Id INT identity(1, 1)
    ,Variable INT
    )
DECLARE @End INT = 0
    ,@start INT = 1
    ,@myvariable INT

INSERT INTO @TableVariable
VALUES (7)
    ,(3)
    ,(2)

WHILE @Start <= @End
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM mytable
    WHERE field1 IN (
            SELECT variable
            FROM @TableVariable
            WHERE Id = @Start
            )

    SET @Start = @Start + 1
END
```

Method-2 using Join

```
 DECLARE @TableVariable TABLE (
        Id INT identity(1, 1)
        ,Variable INT
        )

    INSERT INTO @TableVariable
    VALUES (7)
        ,(3)
        ,(2)

SELECT *
FROM mytable m
INNER JOIN @TableVariable t ON m.field1 = t.Variable
```

Comment: so in option 1 where is myvariable set

Comment: I copied option on in and modified it for my table.  when I run it it says 3 rows affected but not output of the select to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem with Method 1 was the statement Whole @start<= @end when @end is 0.  I changed it to 3 and it works great. Thanks for your help.

DECLARE @TableVariable TABLE (
    Id INT identity(1, 1)
    ,Variable INT
    )
DECLARE @End INT = 3  --Original example had 0
    ,@start INT = 1
    ,@myvariable INT

INSERT INTO @TableVariable
VALUES (7)
    ,(3)
    ,(2)

WHILE @Start <= @End
BEGIN
    SELECT top 100 *
    FROM provider_status PS
    WHERE  PS.provider_status_type_id IN (

```
        SELECT variable
        FROM @TableVariable
        WHERE Id = @Start
        )

SET @Start = @Start + 1
```

I still don't know how @myvariable gets set and used.